# How to display customized fancybox when user presses F5 key or clicks browser's back / close button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display a fancybox using onbeforeunload event or any other possiblities, and instead of native confirm box, i need to display my customized fancybox.

**Here's my current code..**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
     $.fancybox({
          content : 'test'
     });
     return false; // if this line commented, browser won't wait for confirmation
}
```

Please provide working answers. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
function unload(){
  $.fancybox('<div>Your custom element<div>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   window.onbeforeunload=function() {
    unload();
   };
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZQPLVr2RmZNljFnYM5U6?p=preview)

Comment: yes, but after displaying fancybox with yes or no options, the page needs to to wait, until the user selects his option either yes (to reload or close) or no(to stay in the page)..